# CSS3 - How to make one element(preferably a div element) move while hovering over another element?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make one element move, like, from one point to the other by hovering over another div element. But I couldn't figure out how to!

What I want is this:
Say there is a div element, 200x200 and background-color: black.
And there is another, but with background-color:red.
And if perhaps another one, with background-color:green.

They are placed along the center or the screen, vertically. One below the other.
When I hover over one of these, the other two will move from in a right to left direction.
While the one the cursor is hovering over, will remain still.
Any guesses how to do this?

Comment: Do you have any current code you have tried with?

Comment: There's no backward selector in CSS, you probably need to use JavaScript to achieve this.

Comment: @HashemQolami He could use first-child perhaps, or nth-child, if it's always at a set position within the container.

Comment: Some sample HTML would be nice here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can use `.container:hover` and combine it with `:not(:hover)`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XSh9m/2/)**

```
.container:hover .wrapper:not(:hover) .block {
    margin-left: -400px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a pure CSS solution, which should give you an idea of how you can do what you want.

**HTML**

```
<span id="boss">hover here</span>
<div id="move_me"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#move_me {

    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    margin-top:-50px;
    background:#00f; 
    width:100px; 
    height:100px;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
    transition:all 0.5s;
}


#boss {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-left:-50px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    z-index:2;
    background:#ddd;
}


#boss:hover + div {
    left:10%;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
    transition:all 0.5s;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8uzMb/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I have made a solution but it requires a constant width for the main container.In my fiddle the main container is `#blocks` with `width:475px`:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzVbv/2/)

**HTML**

```
<center>
<div id="blocks">
    <div class="innerDiv">
        <div class="block red"></div>
        <div class="block blue"></div>
        <div class="block green"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</center>
```

**CSS**

```
#blocks{
    width:475px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.innerDiv{
    width:50px;
    height:150px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.innerDiv:hover{
    margin-left:0px;
}
.block{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
.block:hover{
    margin-left:213px;
}
.red{
    background-color:red;
}
.blue{
    background-color:blue;
}
.green{
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

General sibling combinator is a slightly more flexible option
[Pen](http://codepen.io/Mrsonord/pen/gLndF)

```
<span id="boss">hover here</span>
<div id="seperator"></div>
<div id="sum">
    <div id="move_me"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#move_me {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    margin-top:-50px;
    background:#00f; 
    width:100px; 
    height:100px;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
    transition:all 0.5s;
}
#boss {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:70px;
    margin-left:-50px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    z-index:2;
    background:#ddd;
}

#boss:hover ~ #sum #move_me {
    left:10%;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
    transition:all 0.5s;
}
```